# Elastichsearch transform document format

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm using elk 6.4.2 and with the Java api I'm fetching all the documents stored in the metricbeat index every 5 minutes.

For example :

```
"system": {
   "core": {
      "nice": {
         "pct": 0
       },
       "system": {
          "pct": 0.0121
       },
```

I would like to configure elasticsearch in the way that it transforms all documents that I fetch in the following format:

```
{
 "module": "system",
 "metric": "core",
 "value": 0,
},
{
 "module": "system",
 "metric": "system",
 "value": 0.0121,
 }
```

or:

```
{
 "module": "system",
 "kpis: [{
   "module": "system",
   "metric": "core",
   "value": 0,
  },
  {
   "module": "system",
   "metric": "system",
   "value": 0.0121,
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **Logstash** to restructure the incoming data shown as stdin() to output through ElasticSearch as stdout(). Check the figure [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/first-event.html) to understand how Logstash acts as a tunnel between your clients and the ES cluster.

Logstash allows you to mutate the fields by creating new fields in your JSON tree or filtering out unneccessary parts. The syntax looks very ugly and hard to learn but given all rules properly it should transform your input to desired outputs. You can mutate by renaming, removing, merging, replacing etc explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html)

Example mutations:

```
if "Invoice_IID" in [msg] {
 mutate {
  add_field => { "Invoice_IID" => "%{msg}" }
}
}

filter {
  mutate {
     copy => { "source_field" => "dest_field" }
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    # Renames the 'HOSTORIP' field to 'client_ip'
    rename => { "HOSTORIP" => "client_ip" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes but in this way I'm changing the format in which the data are stored and then the dashboard (metricbeat) will not work anymore. Is not possible to restructure the data on the fly during the fetch phase? or is not possible to store the data also in another index with the  new format?

Comment: @Fabry can't you restructure it before indexing to ES? I have faced the same issue, and solved it by using another index. while deleting the old index regularly to avoid storage consumption using an external periodic service. not the best possible way, but does the trick for the moment. I would love to see a solution that can do it on the fly, so I can use it as well. Good luck!